# Animating inline svg sprites (<use>) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, sprite

I know that the SVG  element creates a shadow DOM, making it hard to target with CSS and Javascript. Sara Souiedan has [covered some ways](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/) to target the shadow DOM using CSS and mentions it is possible to do using JavaScript.

Can anyone explain how to target the shadow nodes via JavaScript?

Comment: You can apply `id` and `class` attributes to SVG nodes. Why is supposed to be a problem to manipulate nodes with CSS?

Comment: Since I am referencing an SVG with the <use> element, the nodes are now in a shadow DOM and can't be referenced typically with id and class selectors. At least that is my understanding.

Comment: What would you want to do if you could target the shadow DOM? Perhaps there's another way?

Comment: I want to create an arrow icon that draws itself when I hover over a link. I want my arrow icon to be a sprite, instead of it's own file.

Comment: Could you put a minimal test case on a jsfiddle to play with ?

Comment: I tried creating a jsfiddle, but realized it wasn't a good scenario for one. I believe I never mentioned that I'm using an external SVG for the <use> elements to reference. I know Kirill asked if I could just manipulate the nodes directly with id and class attributes. But this doesn't seem to work. I am trying to figure out how to create JavaScript animations on inline svg sprites (<use>) when the SVG is external to the HTML document.